# Extracting property names from PHP object

Tags: php

Given the following array, how can I extract the string representation of the property called ["name"], without brackets or double quotes? I need to be able to extract it without knowing it's name.

Cheers

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($array[0]));

/*it returns
    array(1) 
    {
        ["name"]=>
        string(1) "a"
    }
*/
```

Comment: `echo $array[0]->name;`  or `echo $array[0]['name'];`. Also can you show us the output of only `var_dump($array[0]);`

Comment: No. The first one returns the value. The second one nothing. The third one the whole object. I need to extract the property name, assuming that I don't know what the name is!